# 'Flashbots' object has no attribute 'web3'

Tags: web3.py

I am playing around with flashbots web3 python, trying to send eth using flashbots,   following this
https://github.com/flashbots/web3-flashbots/blob/master/examples/simple.py

On running, I am receiving: `Simulation error 'Flashbots' object has no attribute 'web3.'`

Would someone be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Do a pip uninstall flashbots
And pip install flashbots again

Here is a working example of the same.
This is tested and works.

https://github.com/dev-bhaskar8/simple-flashbots-example/blob/main/flashbots_simple.py